# Laravel session не работает на sharing хостинге

Tags: laravel, сессия, auth

Доброго времени суток !
Проект на Laravel 5.3.* с локалки перенес на хостинг (beget)- перестала работать сессия. 
То есть ,на локалке все работает нормально . 
Не подскажите в чем может быть проблема ?
Ps : также не работает Auth авторизация.(

Comment: Открывайте на сервере лог ошибок (возможно в панели управления он есть) и смотрите содержимое.

Comment: а вот в логах - пустота .
То есть при при выборе данных (языка) - в сессии должно измениться значение Lang - то есть я посылаю пост в контроллер в котором меняю значение сессии 
 ` `
        $value = $request->cur_locale;
        if($value != null || array_key_exists($value , config('app.locales'))|| Session::get('lang') != $value){
            session(['lang' => $value]);
            App::setLocale($value);

            if(Auth::user()){
                return 'modal_lang';
            }else {
                return 'ok_lang';
            }
        } `` 
на локалке работает)

Comment: А с правами там все ок ? на папку storage/framework/sessions, какой вид хранения сессии вы используете ? Возможно нужно как то настроить файловую систему?

Comment: Для  storage выставлял даже 777  - не помогло..- )  На локалке использовал file .. на серваке что только не пробовал ..Сейчас попроблвал обновить на laravel 5.4... как залью отпишусь